# PHP Session Variable Performance

Tags: php, session, performance, shuffle

I was wondering if the code below was the most efficient use of session variables in PHP.

```
<?
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['count']) || !isset($_SESSION['randomArray'])) {
  $count = 0;
  $randomArray = array();
  $sql="SELECT youtubeurl FROM Foodlist";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       array_push($randomArray,$row['youtubeurl']);
  }
  shuffle($randomArray);
  $_SESSION['randomArray'] = $randomArray;
  $_SESSION['count'] = $count; 
} elseif ($_SESSION['count'] >= sizeof($_SESSION['randomArray'])){
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
  $randomArray = $_SESSION['randomArray'];
  shuffle($randomArray);
  $_SESSION['randomArray'] = $randomArray;
} else{
  $randomArray = $_SESSION['randomArray'];
  $count = $_SESSION['count'];
  echo $randomArray[$count];
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}
?>
```

The intent of the code should be obvious, if I did it correctly.  But basically there exists an list(randomArray) of strings which is looped through once.  After each complete pass, the list is shuffled.  Every element prints out once before any single element is printed out twice.

So, is this the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd simplify this as follows:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['randomList'])) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT youtubeurl FROM Foodlist"); // or die(mysql_error())
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $_SESSION['randomList'][] = $row['youtubeurl'];
    }
    shuffle($_SESSION['randomList']);
}

echo array_shift($_SESSION['randomList']);
```